Is there a difference between saddle-point and steepest descent methods?
In this paper there is a clear distinction between steepest descent method and saddle-point approximation method. Eg. in the first page it says:

Indeed, Picard-Lefschetz theory establishes that a saddle point can contribute to the path integral only if the saddle point can be approached from the original contour along a steepest descent contour.

There are other examples also. Am I misunderstanding the statement? Aren’t the two methods the same?

This question is similar to: How is the Saddle point approximation used in physics?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See Simulated annealing

Thanks for pointing this out. I am not sure what is the relation between the method of steepest descent and saddle-point approximation to edit/remove the question. Could you explain this to me? Thank you in advance.

It looks like they are the same.   Or at the very least, Wikipedia starts its page on the topic with "In mathematics, the method of steepest descent or saddle-point method is an extension of Laplace's method for approximating an integral, where one deforms a contour integral in the complex plane to pass near a stationary point (saddle point), in roughly the direction of steepest descent or stationary phase"  So at least one wikipedia author claims they are the same thing.

I've not used it myself, so I'm just reading between the lines, but since it's designed to support a path integral and specifies properties relating to the 0's of the derivatives, its highly likely to be related to Lagrangian mechanics or one of the subsequent topics that expanded on those ideas.  You may find some traction looking for what kind of physics problems need to do path integrals in complex spaces in the first place.  It's easier to find a kind of formulation than it is to find a particular way to solve said formulation.

@CortAmmon if you’re going to go  by Wikipedia then the two methods have different pages on Wikipedia.

@Y2H can you link me to the one on saddle point?  I tried to look it up the obvious way, and found that Saddle Point Method redirects to method of steepest descent.  If you can link me to the other method, I might be able to divine some difference.

Regarding your quote, I reserve the right to be wrong, but it looks to me like it talks of saddle points and paths of steepest descent, not necessarily two methods leveraging saddle points and paths of steepest descent.  It feels a bit like yin and yang, or time-points and durations between those time points.  They're two things that go together.

Related and possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/805059/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27516/226902

Brief summary:

The steepest descent method and the saddle-point approximation method are the same.

The stationary phase approximation is the special case when the integrand is a phase.

Concerning OP's quote, note that generically only a subset of the saddle points contributes to the integral in the asymptotic limit.
For an example, see e.g. my Math.SE answer here.

Laplace's method is for a real integrand and without contour deformation.

In the WKB approximation, the starting point is a wavefunction Ansatz for a differential equation rather than an integral.



Qmechanic's answer is just too good.
I'd like to add that both Laplace's method and stationary phase approximations are integrals along the real number line, covering two opposite cases, and are today correctly taught as if they were lemmas on the way to the steepest descent method, which is also known as saddle point method.
The crucial addition is the contour deformation: from the original contour, nudge the contour to reduce the integral to either the stationary phase approximation case, or much much more commonly, to the Laplace's method case. This latter case is why the method is called steepest descent, and tells us what to do when we encounter a saddle point. It also makes it clear that only the saddle points reached by the appropriate nudging of the contour from the original, would contribute. Saddle points that are not along the nudged contour do not contribute.
Needless to say, the lemma-like presentation of these topics encourages students to conflate them, that all of these things are grouped together as steepest descent, not least since the main result obtained is powerful enough to also solve the specific cases earlier. This might be intentional. The important part is to be able to apply what is taught, and if students always bring out the big guns, they will also always get answers, so who cares if the conflation is happening.
Note that if the contour deformation is to reduce the complicated integral into the stationary phase approximation case, i.e. making the magnitude = constant rather than phase = constant, then it is definitely not a steepest descent anything. But, apparently, the constant phase method is a lot easier to work with and get correct answers, than the constant magnitude method. That is, the steepest descent down a few saddle points is a lot easier to work with than getting all the stationary phase contributions along the constant magnitude contour.
